# Flattening a complex XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

[XML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AayWZ.jpg)

```
    <Root>
     <Property>
          <CollectionID>ESTATE_APPRAISAL</CollectionID>
          <CollectionTypeCode>003</CollectionTypeCode>
        <Valuation>
           <PropertyReference>
                    <ID>CONTRIBUTIONFACTOR</ID>
           </PropertyReference>
           <ValueGroup>
           <PropertyValue>
              <NameSpecification>
                  <Name>CF 4 - General Purpose Asset</Name>
              </NameSpecification>
           </PropertyValue>
           </ValueGroup>
        </Valuation>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation>
   </Property>
   <Property>
      <CollectionID>ESTATE_APPRAISAL</CollectionID>
      <CollectionTypeCode>003</CollectionTypeCode>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation>
      <Valuation>...</Valuation> 
   </Property>
   </Root>
```

Hi All, Above is the XML structure which i need to flatten to receive an XML with one node as Property. The issue i'm having is there are multiple nodes for Valuation which i need to loop.

When i do a for-each tag it only bring values upto the first valuation node and it goes into the next property for processing. In the example i have included having only one property structure. There are multiples like these in the full xml file, structure is similar for other properties as well.

I need a data to be appear in a table like structure
Collection ID, TypeCode, Property Reference, Property Value

Thanks All.

Comment: Please the XML snippet as a code block inside your question. Nobody wants to manually type in your XML for his answer. Also give an example of the desired result in a code block. Also the XSLT that you came up with in another code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Properties>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Valuation">
        <Property>
          <xsl:attribute name="CollectionID">
            <xsl:value-of select="../CollectionID"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="TypeCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="../CollectionTypeCode"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="PropertyReference">
            <xsl:value-of select="PropertyReference/ID"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="PropertyValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="ValueGroup/PropertyValue/NameSpecification/Name"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </Property>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Properties>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```